# Preparing cut vegetables for the next day?

Tags: eggplant, zucchini

To speed up lunch cooking, I'm considering pre-cutting some veggies the day before.

I often do quick meals with zucchini and eggplant and both do seem to be not too well suited for cutting and then storing them in the fridge for like 18 hours. (If I cut them the evening before.)

Are there any tricks for "pre-preparing" these?

Answer (score 4):

I find that a small amount of acid helps prevent the ugly browning and "sliminess" that may occur, however many foods like eggplant, okra, etc. that rely mostly on their moisture for structure, tend to be the poorest performers. I've had more luck cooking certain vegetables like this in advance then refrigerating, than I have trying to prep in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some veggies which you could precut and store in the fridge (e.g., carrots), but they may dry out a little.
The veggies you specified (zucchini and eggplant) are a little harder to precut. What you might try is storing them in water. However, eggplant can act like a sponge so I have no idea how it will turn out.